# Edge linking in c#

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I have detected edges in gray image using canny operator. Now want to fit circle/ellipse in edges.
I donot know is there any way in c# to cluster/ linking these edges so that I can find edge boundaries and properties as well known in mAtlab.

regards,

Comment: What edges are you talking about? Can you post some code?

Comment: Are you talking about a graph data structure?

Answer (score 0):

I might try the [Hough transform](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hough.htm); it's not fast, but fairly easy to implement and use.
It could be used to detect lines, circles, ellipses, but can be generalized further if you have to. Here is an example of the [Circular Hough Transform](http://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg782/lectures/lecture_10/lec782_05_10.pdf).

Comment: If you perform Hough transform, you don't need to find the contour at all.